# Como enviar e-mail com HTML Customizado do Appender SMTP no log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

Tenho o log sendo enviado por e-mail que funciona corretamente com modelo html default,
preciso usar o html customizado, criei uma classe CustomHtmlLayout(plugin) que extende de AbstractStringLayout, como a classe org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.HtmlLayout, só com algumas alterações.
Como eu configuro no log4j2.xml para ser usado essa minha classe?

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" packages="com.caminho.utils">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}[%M] %-5p %C - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="LogToFile" fileName="/work1/agendamento.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <SMTP name="LogToMail"  
              subject="Erro na API de Agendamento"
              from="email"
              to="destino"
              smtpHost="smtp.gmail.com"
              smtpPort="465"
              smtpProtocol="smtps"
              smtpUsername="usuario"
              smtpPassword="senha"
              bufferSize="100"
        >
            
        </SMTP>
        
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="debugar" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="erro" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToMail"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToMail"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Classe que deve customizar o html**

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomHtmlLayout", category = Node.CATEGORY, elementType = Layout.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
public class CustomHtmlLayout extends AbstractStringLayout {

    /**
     * Default font family: {@value}.
     */
    public static final String DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY = "arial,sans-serif";

    private static final String TRACE_PREFIX = "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    private static final String REGEXP = Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR.equals("\n") ? "\n" : Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR + "|\n";
    private static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Log4j Log Messages";
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html";
    private static final String DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN = "JVM_ELAPSE_TIME";

    private final long jvmStartTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime();

    // Print no location info by default
    private final boolean locationInfo;
    private final String title;
    private final String contentType;
    private final String font;
    private final String fontSize;
    private final String headerSize;
    private final DatePatternConverter datePatternConverter;

    /**
     * Possible font sizes
     */
    public enum FontSize {
        SMALLER("smaller"), XXSMALL("xx-small"), XSMALL("x-small"), SMALL("small"), MEDIUM("medium"), LARGE("large"),
        XLARGE("x-large"), XXLARGE("xx-large"), LARGER("larger");

        private final String size;

        FontSize(final String size) {
            this.size = size;
        }

        public String getFontSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public static FontSize getFontSize(final String size) {
            for (final FontSize fontSize : values()) {
                if (fontSize.size.equals(size)) {
                    return fontSize;
                }
            }
            return SMALL;
        }

        public FontSize larger() {
            return this.ordinal() < XXLARGE.ordinal() ? FontSize.values()[this.ordinal() + 1] : this;
        }
    }

    private CustomHtmlLayout(final boolean locationInfo, final String title, final String contentType, final Charset charset,
            final String font, final String fontSize, final String headerSize, final String datePattern,
            final String timezone) {
        super(charset);
        this.locationInfo = locationInfo;
        this.title = title + "ERRRROUUUUUUU";
        this.contentType = addCharsetToContentType(contentType);
        this.font = font;
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
        this.headerSize = headerSize;
        this.datePatternConverter = DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN.equals(datePattern) ? null
                : DatePatternConverter.newInstance(new String[]{datePattern, timezone});
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title + "Teste do Jeff";
    }

    /**
     * For testing purposes.
     */
    public boolean isLocationInfo() {
        return locationInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLocation() {
        return locationInfo;
    }

    private String addCharsetToContentType(final String contentType) {
        if (contentType == null) {
            return DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE + "; charset=" + getCharset();
        }
        return contentType.contains("charset") ? contentType : contentType + "; charset=" + getCharset();
    }

    @Override
    public String toSerializable(final LogEvent event) {
        final StringBuilder sbuf = getStringBuilder();

        sbuf.append("<h1> CHAMBRA AQUI MEU</h1>");
        sbuf.append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR).append("<tr>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);

        sbuf.append("<td>");

        if (datePatternConverter == null) {
            sbuf.append(event.getTimeMillis() - jvmStartTime);
        } else {
            datePatternConverter.format(event, sbuf);
        }
        sbuf.append("</td>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);

        final String escapedThread = Transform.escapeHtmlTags(event.getThreadName());
        sbuf.append("<td title=\"").append(escapedThread).append(" thread\">");
        sbuf.append(escapedThread);
        sbuf.append("</td>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);

        sbuf.append("<td title=\"Level\">");
        if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.DEBUG)) {
            sbuf.append("<font color=\"#339933\">");
            sbuf.append(Transform.escapeHtmlTags(String.valueOf(event.getLevel())));
            sbuf.append("</font>");
        } else if (event.getLevel().isMoreSpecificThan(Level.WARN)) {
            sbuf.append("<font color=\"#993300\"><strong>");
            sbuf.append(Transform.escapeHtmlTags(String.valueOf(event.getLevel())));
            sbuf.append("</strong></font>");
        } else {
            sbuf.append(Transform.escapeHtmlTags(String.valueOf(event.getLevel())));
        }
        sbuf.append("</td>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);

        String escapedLogger = Transform.escapeHtmlTags(event.getLoggerName());
        if (Strings.isEmpty(escapedLogger)) {
            escapedLogger = LoggerConfig.ROOT;
        }
        sbuf.append("<td title=\"").append(escapedLogger).append(" logger\">");
        sbuf.append(escapedLogger);
        sbuf.append("</td>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);

        if (locationInfo) {
            final StackTraceElement element = event.getSource();
            sbuf.append("<td>");
            sbuf.append(Transform.escapeHtmlTags(element.getFileName()));
            sbuf.append(':');
            sbuf.append(element.getLineNumber());
            sbuf.append("</td>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }

        sbuf.append("<td title=\"Message\">");
        sbuf.append(Transform.escapeHtmlTags(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage()).replaceAll(REGEXP, "<br />"));
        sbuf.append("</td>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        sbuf.append("</tr>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);

        if (event.getContextStack() != null && !event.getContextStack().isEmpty()) {
            sbuf.append("<tr><td bgcolor=\"#EEEEEE\" style=\"font-size : ").append(fontSize);
            sbuf.append(";\" colspan=\"6\" ");
            sbuf.append("title=\"Nested Diagnostic Context\">");
            sbuf.append("NDC: ").append(Transform.escapeHtmlTags(event.getContextStack().toString()));
            sbuf.append("</td></tr>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }

        if (event.getContextData() != null && !event.getContextData().isEmpty()) {
            sbuf.append("<tr><td bgcolor=\"#EEEEEE\" style=\"font-size : ").append(fontSize);
            sbuf.append(";\" colspan=\"6\" ");
            sbuf.append("title=\"Mapped Diagnostic Context\">");
            sbuf.append("MDC: ").append(Transform.escapeHtmlTags(event.getContextData().toMap().toString()));
            sbuf.append("</td></tr>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }

        final Throwable throwable = event.getThrown();
        if (throwable != null) {
            sbuf.append("<tr><td bgcolor=\"#993300\" style=\"color:White; font-size : ").append(fontSize);
            sbuf.append(";\" colspan=\"6\">");
            appendThrowableAsHtml(throwable, sbuf);
            sbuf.append("</td></tr>").append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }

        return sbuf.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    private void appendThrowableAsHtml(final Throwable throwable, final StringBuilder sbuf) {
        final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        try {
            throwable.printStackTrace(pw);
        } catch (final RuntimeException ex) {
            // Ignore the exception.
        }
        pw.flush();
        final LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(sw.toString()));
        final ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                lines.add(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            if (ex instanceof InterruptedIOException) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            lines.add(ex.toString());
        }
        boolean first = true;
        for (final String line : lines) {
            if (!first) {
                sbuf.append(TRACE_PREFIX);
            } else {
                first = false;
            }
            sbuf.append(Transform.escapeHtmlTags(line));
            sbuf.append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }
    }

    private StringBuilder appendLs(final StringBuilder sbuilder, final String s) {
        sbuilder.append(s).append(Strings.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        return sbuilder;
    }

    private StringBuilder append(final StringBuilder sbuilder, final String s) {
        sbuilder.append(s);
        return sbuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getHeader() {
        final StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
        append(sbuf, "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" ");
        appendLs(sbuf, "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<html>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<head>");
        append(sbuf, "<meta charset=\"");
        append(sbuf, getCharset().toString());
        appendLs(sbuf, "\"/>");
        append(sbuf, "<title>").append(title);
        appendLs(sbuf, "</title>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<style type=\"text/css\">");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<!--");
        append(sbuf, "body, table {font-family:").append(font).append("; font-size: ");
        appendLs(sbuf, headerSize).append(";}");
        appendLs(sbuf, "th {background: #336699; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left;}");
        appendLs(sbuf, "-->");
        appendLs(sbuf, "</style>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "</head>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<body bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" topmargin=\"6\" leftmargin=\"6\">");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<hr size=\"1\" noshade=\"noshade\">");
        appendLs(sbuf, "Log session start time " + new java.util.Date() + "<br>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<br>");
        appendLs(sbuf,
                "<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\" border=\"1\" bordercolor=\"#224466\" width=\"100%\">");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<tr>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<th>Time</th>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<th>Thread</th>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<th>Level</th>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<th>Logger</th>");
        if (locationInfo) {
            appendLs(sbuf, "<th>File:Line</th>");
        }
        appendLs(sbuf, "<th>Message</th>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "</tr>");
        return sbuf.toString().getBytes(getCharset());
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getFooter() {
        final StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
        appendLs(sbuf, "</table>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "<br>");
        appendLs(sbuf, "</body></html>");
        return getBytes(sbuf.toString());
    }

    public static CustomHtmlLayout createDefaultLayout() {
        return newBuilder().build();
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static Builder newBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder implements org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Builder<CustomHtmlLayout> {

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private boolean locationInfo = false;

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private String title = DEFAULT_TITLE;

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private String contentType = null; // defer default value in order to use specified charset

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private FontSize fontSize = FontSize.SMALL;

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private String fontName = DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY;

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private String datePattern = DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN;

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private String timezone = null; // null means default timezone

        private Builder() {

        }

        public Builder setLocationInfo(final boolean locationInfo) {
            this.locationInfo = locationInfo;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setTitle(final String title) {
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setContentType(final String contentType) {
            this.contentType = contentType;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setCharset(final Charset charset) {
            this.charset = charset;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setFontSize(final FontSize fontSize) {
            this.fontSize = fontSize;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setFontName(final String fontName) {
            this.fontName = fontName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setDatePattern(final String datePattern) {
            this.datePattern = datePattern;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setTimezone(final String timezone) {
            this.timezone = timezone;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public CustomHtmlLayout build() {
            if (contentType == null) {
                contentType = DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE + "; charset=" + charset;
            }
            return new CustomHtmlLayout(locationInfo, title, contentType, charset, fontName, fontSize.getFontSize(),
                    fontSize.larger().getFontSize(), datePattern, timezone);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deixando registro para outros, como deu certo no meu cenário.
Criei um plug-in que será o Layout a ser usado, tem essa anotação:

```
@Plugin(name = "MyHtmlLayout", category = Node.CATEGORY, elementType = Layout.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
public class MyHtmlLayout extends AbstractStringLayout {
//...codigos
}
```

é mencionado no arquivo de configuração log4j2.xml, dentro da tag do apennder que deseja usar o layout customizado, e informando o packages da classe na tag Configuration, assim:

```
<Configuration status="WARN" packages="log.layout">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="File" fileName="output.html" bufferedIO="false"
            advertiseURI="file://path/to/output.log" advertise="true">
            <MyHtmlLayout datePattern="ISO8601" timezone="GMT-3" />
        </File>
    <SMTP name="Mail" subject="Erro No projeto do Jeff"
            from="email"
            to="email" smtpHost="smtp.gmail.com"
            smtpPort="465" smtpProtocol="smtps"
            smtpUsername="email"
            smtpPassword="senha" bufferSize="100">
            <MyHtmlLayout datePattern="ISO8601" timezone="GMT-3" />
        </SMTP>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Mail" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```